# Different Behavior using base argument in Pandas resampling dependent on resampling frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, resampling

I am struggling with the "base" argument using pandas **resample**:

Below there is a minimal example with 5 minutes data. I am using **Pandas 0.25.1**.
The aim is to get a rolling mean with a windowsize of 24h, but only once every hour (green points).
That's why I am using the "base" argument in pandas resample and shift it.

If the resampling frequency is 23h everything is as expected (upper subplot).
But with 24h (lower subplot) there is a different behavior: It seems like the base argument has no effect at all, the green points overlap.

Edit for clarification: The function I'd like to apply can be any arbitrary function and doesn't have to be the "mean()". I only used "mean()" for convenience.

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
%matplotlib inline

register_matplotlib_converters()

df_5min = pd.DataFrame()
df_5min['DATETIME']=pd.date_range("2020-01-13 00:00:00", "2020-01-15 23:55:00", freq="5min")
df_5min.set_index('DATETIME', inplace=True)

t=np.linspace(0,6.28*3,len(df_5min.index))
df_5min['RAW']=np.cos(t)*t+t

df_5min['RAW_rolling_24h']=df_5min['RAW'].rolling(pd.Timedelta('24 hour')).mean()

result=[]
for base in range(0,24, 1):
    s=(df_5min['RAW'].resample(pd.Timedelta('24 hour'), base=base, loffset=pd.Timedelta('24 hour')).mean())
    s.rename('RAW_resampled_24h', inplace=True)
    result.append(s)
df_5min_resampled_24h = pd.concat(result)


df_5min['RAW_rolling_23h']=df_5min['RAW'].rolling(pd.Timedelta('23 hour')).mean()

result=[]
for base in range(0,23, 1):
    s=(df_5min['RAW'].resample(pd.Timedelta('23 hour'), base=base, loffset=pd.Timedelta('23 hour')).mean())
    s.rename('RAW_resampled_23h', inplace=True)
    result.append(s)
df_5min_resampled_23h = pd.concat(result)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(17,12),sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(df_5min['RAW'], color='blue', label='RAW')
ax[0].plot(df_5min['RAW_rolling_23h'], color='red', label='RAW rolling mean 23h')
ax[0].plot(df_5min_resampled_23h, 'o', color='green',alpha=0.3, label='RAW resampled 23h sliding base')
ax[0].legend(loc='upper left')

ax[1].plot(df_5min['RAW'], color='blue', label='RAW')
ax[1].plot(df_5min['RAW_rolling_24h'], color='red', label='RAW rolling mean 24h')
ax[1].plot(df_5min_resampled_24h, 'o', color='green',alpha=0.3, label='RAW resampled 24h sliding base')
ax[1].legend(loc='upper left')

ax[0].set_xlim("2020-01-13 00:00:00", "2020-01-16 00:30:00")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: maybe have a look here
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24127

Comment: Thank you, but I guess this doesn't help me at all

Comment: It does appear to be a bug - the resampling works correctly for any number of hours which is not an integer factor of 24h (perhaps it is related to the logic error which caused [24127](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24127). I would suggest opening an issue on github, but you may need to do the resampling manually in the meantime

Comment: Thank you. I've just taken a closer look at it. I'm not sure anymore if it's a bug, I guess it's just how the way the base argument is supposed to work. I've also seen that there is an open request on github for a rolling window with step size: [15354](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15354)